# ST_MakeLine not returning proper latitude/longitude values

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table consisting of latitude, longitude and geom values:

```
 index |         longitude         |         latitude          |                        geom                        | cluster_id 
-------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------
 18002 | 10.5185737487922670000000 | 52.2491934541062800000000 | 0101000020110F00000CCD0946EADD3141FD8A5F36DF1C5A41 |          1
 19088 | 10.5185833538704580000000 | 52.2492122543443860000000 | 0101000020110F00002A04C357EBDD314170632611E01C5A41 |          1
 20256 | 10.5185842237361060000000 | 52.2492442532568550000000 | 0101000020110F000058108D70EBDD3141FECB8485E11C5A41 |          1
  9420 | 10.5185872545577310000000 | 52.2492660247580400000000 | 0101000020110F00003139ECC6EBDD31417342DF82E21C5A41 |          1
```

I calculated my geom column like so:

`UPDATE coordinates SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326), 3857)`

I calculate the `cluster_id` in my python script by using a clustering algorithm (DBSCAN).

I am attempting to make a LineString within clusters, using this query:

`SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_MakeLine(v.geom)) FROM (SELECT geom FROM vehicle_coordinates WHERE cluster_id = 1) as v;`

An example of result of the query is:
`[[1173235.91018827,6845036.84972168],[1173242.1166575,6845037.7691405],[1173248.6137255,6845039.6218353],[1173253.66564705,6845041.21341728]]`

Obviously this doesn't make sense as they should be valid GPS coordinates. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Don't rely on distances in 3857. At such latitude the distortion is huge, greater than 40%. Instead use a local projection (UTM or else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
UPDATE coordinates 
 SET geom = ST_Transform(
             ST_SetSRID(
               ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),
               4326
               ),
             3857
            )
```

is transforming your lat-long coordinates in the two columns into a geometry in SRID 3857, which is not degrees lat-long - its a cartesian system used by Google Maps (and other web map systems) and is approximately a measure in metres.

This is what you probably want for a clustering algorithm so your distances are in metres. To get back to lat-long, transform your geometry to SRID 4326. I *think*

```
update coordinate set geom = st_transform(geom, 4326);
```

*might* do it - if not then help on transforming PostGIS coordinate systems should be easily found.

Comment: Oh yeah, I needed to transform it into a Cartesian system as I needed to do some additional calculations based on distance in meters. That's why it's in that state.

Comment: You were right. Looks like after I changed my column to 4326 and recalculated the geom value, I'm getting appropriate coordinates.